# If I have welding procedure (QW-403) for carbon steel material S275JR, can I use it to weld carbon steel material for Q355B? Need for separate WPS?

Tags: metallurgy

I have a project where the material of carbon steel plates to be used is S275JR and S355JR. Our Chinese supplier could not manage to get S275JR or S355JR but rather prefers to use Q355B which is equivalent grade. My client is insisting on me doing another welding procedures as well as qualify the welders again with Chinese material.

Is this correct as per standard and which standard? I am of the opinion that they are same material (chemical composition) and no need of separate proceures and welders qualifying.

Comment: It is correct per every standard that one must verify results are per that standard. In some cases, one must qualify per batch. In others, per supplier. Give in to the whims of your customer if you want to keep them. You should however bill them appropriately for all they want and get.